# «Глазами обрастаю, как листвой» — смысл фразы

Tags: лексика, семантика, поэзия, окказионализмы

*В прохладе утренней, где дышится так сладко,

**Глазами обрастаю, как листвой,**

А в небесах воздухоплавает лошадка —

Такое облако и облик столь живой,*

*Из обольстительных и тающих материй,

Из капель, дуновений и лучей.

Вмиг растворясь, — такой прозрачной стать потерей,

Не воскрешаемой из груды мелочей!..*

*Люблю я это превратительное дело,

Не глядя под ноги, глядеть на облака,

Где, превращаясь в превратительное тело,

Исчезновений возвращается река.*
[**Юнна Мориц**](http://www.liveinternet.ru/users/kirovogradka/post406022796/)

Очень бы хотелось понять: **что** имеет в виду поэтесса?
**Каков смысл** ее фразы *глазами обрастаю, как листвой*?
Поделитесь, пожалуйста, своим виденьем, своим представлением изображенной картины.

Comment: Что хочет сказать Юнна Мориц, это вопрос уже медицинский. А что за ЖЖ по ссылке? Нужно хотя бы время написания этого текста. Последние десять-пятнадцать лет - это сразу "в печку", там смысла уже нет. По - стилю похоже что именно так.

Comment: Будьте любезны, соблюдайте правила Форума и правила приличия. Юнна Мориц — известная поэтесса, ее многие знают и любят, цитируют. (А о Вас мы пока ничего не знаем — и не цитируем.) Имейте хотя бы просто уважение — к женщине в возрасте... А что такое "ЖЖ" — в Вашем понимании — я не знаю.

Comment: У меня было два вопроса к вам. 1. Что за ЖЖ пор вашей ссылке? Чей именно? Если не её личный, то где гарантия, что это её стихи?! 2. Год написания. Вы ни на один не отвектили.  Про возраст тех, кто её любит - тоже в печку. Мне интересно знать, когда это написано, до или после достижения ей стадии поэтического маразма.

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, Юнна хочет сказать, что бывают такие моменты, что видишь не только глазами, а как бы чувствуешь всем телом, у тебя везде "глаза", тогда увидишь нечто удивительное, "превратительное тело".

Её метафоры иногда фантастичны, а иногда, наоборот, рисуют картинку, возвращающую прямое значение словам в переносном смысле. Ребёнок вот сразу увидит картинку: фигура человека, из которого растут ветки с глазами, человек, видящий всё и всё чувствующий.

Она сама говорила, что в её стихи нужно "изнутри вглядываться".
Вот ещё образы  этого же плана:

*Из пятен света попадая в пятна тьмы,

Я покрывалась воздуха глазами,

Читая незабвенные псалмы

По книге звёздной, чьи глаза над нами.

Волнами сквозь меня, светясь, текло

Пространство ритмов, что гораздо глубже окон.

И в чёрных списках было мне светло,

И многолюдно в одиночестве глубоком.*

Comment: "Когда мы были молодые. И чушь прекрасную несли..." — наверно, пришло МОЁ время для того, чтобы понять Поэтку. Спасибо Вам за высокоОбразность и глубину...  Только Юнна может сказать:  «Люблю свою страну, и это – внутривенно»!

Comment: Рада встретить человека, разделяющего мою "привязанность"(не будем зря трепать слово любовь) к поэту, вобравшему в себя и традиции золотого века поэзии, и символизма. Кстати, Пушкин бы тоже не понял метафор символистов, назвал бы таких поэтов психами, так что не обижайтесь на тех, кто не понимает Юнну, до неё нужно дорасти и чуть-чуть вернуться в детство, она ж для детей много писала. Вот они её любили и понимали.